# Backbone.js, ASP.NET, WCF Service, JSON

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, service, backbone.js

I'm about to create a small web app on Asp.Net 3.5.
Thought this time maybe I should try using Backbone.js..
Is it practical/easy to implement?
I've just spent the whole day trying to set up a WCF Service to return Json without positive results.
I would love to hear the best path for implementation from someone who has already used Backbone.js with Asp.Net.
Alternatively I would love to hear of alternatives that are easy to integrate with Asp.Net.

Answer (score 1):

> I've just spent the whole day trying to set up a WCF Service to return
>   Json without positive results.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WCF_JQUERY_ASMX.aspx), is short and straight to the point.

> Thought this time maybe I should try using Backbone.js.. Is it
>   practical/easy to implement?

Well... as usual, it basically depend on what you want to do. Backbone can help you if you want to implement the MVC pattern in your client-side code, but it requires some time to get into the APIs so if your goal for the moment is just to create and consume a WCF service using Javascript you could consider using jQuery or MooTools and then switch to Backbone if you need.

PS
[Here](http://thomasdavis.github.com/2011/02/01/backbone-introduction.html) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/) you'll find two quickstart backbone tutorials.

Comment: Actually I find backbone.js to be pretty simple to understand, I have experience with jQuery. 
What I'm looking into is actually integrating between the two WCF & Backbone.js in the most straight forward way (i.e less coding).
I was asking about alternatives to Backbone.js as in client MVC frameworks.

Comment: I see. Take also a look at Javascript MVC: http://javascriptmvc.com/, it has also a nice focus on testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REST Singleton Service template` in the [WCF REST Starter Kit Project Templates](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest) to get WCF with JSON support up and running quickly.